# C++ Visual Studio Community 2019 SFML Link Short Cut

Tags: c++, sfml

I want to make sfml projects. I downloaded sfml and linked my project(paste dlls to project folder and link in the properties).This is so long way.Is there any shortcut way of this ? Thank you.

Comment: NuGet comes to mind...

Comment: I've used VCPKG in the past with SFML, once it is installed, any project you make with Visual Studio will be automatically linked with SFML, no need to copy files or link manually. I have not tried VCPKG with anything else so I can not confirm if it would work with anything else.